# Copy file to docker container via Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-cp

I want to copy a file to a docker container, as one of my Ansible playbook steps. I create the file with jinja2 "template". I can copy the file in /tmp/ and the run a command to copy it to the docker container, such as: 
`docker cp /tmp/config.json my_image:/app/config/path/`

But I'm looking for the better way not to use "/tmp" or like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible has a [`docker` connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_connection.html) that you can use to interact with existing containers in your playbook.  For example, if I have a container named `mycontainer`:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND       CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
07899303ac55   alpine    "sleep inf"   7 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds             mycontainer
```

I can create an Ansible inventory like this that sets the `ansible_connection` variable to `community.general.docker`:

```
all:
  hosts:
    mycontainer:
      ansible_connection: community.docker.docker
```

Now I can target the container in a play like this:

```
- hosts: mycontainer
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: create target directory in container
      file:
        path: /target
        state: directory

    - name: copy a file into the container
      copy:
        src: example.file
        dest: /target/example.file
```